# Why is the if conditional set to !false?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is taken from another question of mine. Where the code below was given as an answer, though i'm not quite sure what is happening in it.

The aim is to only fetch userid once at the start instead of fetching it everytime fetchupdate() is called.

```
var delay = 300000, userIdFetched = false;
function GetUpdate(status)
{
    if(status == "fail")        
    {
        setTimeout(function(){
            fetchupdate();
        },delay * 2);<-- need to make this double itself
    }
    else
    {
        setTimeout(function(){
            fetchupdate();
        },delay);
    }
};


function fetchupdate(){
    var userid=$_SESSION['UserID'];
    $.ajax()
    {
        type:"POST",
        url:"getupdates.php",
        data:{userid: userid},
        complete:function(data,status)
        {
            if(status == true)
            {
                if(!userIdFetched){ <----Why is this set to !userIdFetched instead of userIdFetched
                    userIdFetched = true;
                    //Get the user Id here 
                }
                $("#Updates").text(data);
                GetUpdate("success");//Changed to String
            }
            else
            {
                $("#Updates").text("You have no updates.")
                GetUpdate("fail");//Changed to String
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Question:

Why is the if condition set to

```
if(!userIdFetched)
```

which evaluates to (!false) --> if(true), which causes the code in the if block to run, after which userIdFetched is set to true?

Shouldn't the if conditional be set to

```
if(userIdFetched)
```

which should cause the code in the if block to run, after which userIdFetched would be set to true, to represent the userid being fetched?

I would appreciate someone clarifying this up for me if possible.

Comment: If there's no `userIdFetched`, then you need to fetch it right? So the condition is *"if no userIDFetched is present, fetch it"*. That's what you're doing when you do `if (!userIdFetched) {`. You're confirming the truth of the statement that there is no value there.

Comment: `if (!userIdFetched)` succeeds means `userIdFetched` is `false`. Then it would only make sense for the block of that `if` to reset it to `true`.

Comment: If the negation is confusing *(and that's not uncommon)*, then make it a positive assertion with an `else` statement. `if (userIdFetched) { /* nothing to do here */ } else { /* fetch it */ userIdFetched = true; }`

Comment: @cookiemonster Given that if x = 1 , y = 2 therefore x != y,shouldn't it be other way round,if(userIdFetched)<--if the condition (userIdFetched= false) IS true, you should fetch it?

Comment: @Kenneth.J: I'm not sure exactly what you mean. If I understand your question, the `userIdFetched` variable is used as a flag to tell you if the ID has been fetched yet. If that flag is set to `false`, then you need to: ***1)*** Fetch the ID, and ***2)*** set the flag to `true` so that you don't fetch it again next time around. ... Then the next time the code runs, it'll see that `userIdFetched` is `true`, so it won't need to fetch it again. It doesn't need to set it back to `false` unless you want it to do the fetch again in the future.

Comment: @cookiemonster yep thats it exactly, it's just the use of if(!userIdFetched) that i can't seem to get my head around. From your example above, shouldnt

    if(userIdFetched) = if(userIdFetched == false)? In which case we should be fetching the user id? However in your example, that is not the case?

Comment: No, the way the `if` statement works is that it simply evaluates the "truthy-ness" of whatever it is given. So if `userIdFetched` is `false`, that's clearly not a true value. So when you do `if (userIdFetched) {` when `userIdFetched` is `false`, it will not let the code for the `if` statement run, because the value it was given did not evaluate to `true`, so it'll pass it over to the `else` statement. However, if you do `if (!userIdFetched) {`, now you're "flipping" the truthy-ness of `userIdFetched` before passing it. So if `userIdFetched` is `false`, the `if` will receive the value `true`.

Comment: ...put it this way, the `if` statement can't know what you're thinking, nor does it know the name of the variable or its meaning. It only gets a value, which it interprets as the value `true` or the value `false`. This makes variable naming very important, not for the computer, but for the humans reading and interpreting it. Because of this, it's often better to use clear names that allow you to use their natural value instead of their "negated" value. So if you changed your variable to `var need_to_get_user_id = true;`, and then `if (need_to_get_user_id) { ... }`, it may make more sense.

Comment: @cookiemonster Ahhh i think i get it now... to paraphrase, the code in the if block only runs when the IF conditional evaluates to TRUE.However as i set userIfFetched to FALSE, the code in the IF block will never run, since a value of TRUE is needed.Which is where the ! comes in?

Comment: @Kenneth.J: Exactly. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it should be `if(!userIdFetched)`, because you only need to enter the `if`-block when `userIdFetched` is `false`. If it's `true`, then there's no need to enter the `if`-block.

It might help to think of it as being roughly equivalent to:

```
if(userIdFetched == false)
```

Although there are some difference in how `x == false` and `!x` works with regard to some 'falsey' values ([demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/8SA59/)). In your case, since you're only dealing with Boolean values, this is not an issue.